# Unknown UDP trafic on fresh Ubuntu 12.04 install

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

I do configure ufw to deny outgoing trafic by default.
On a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 install, I always get some random-like UDP trafic.

I am curious to what generates this & how should I allow it (if I should).

> http://www.cloudshark.org/captures/84a949429ebf

```
Apr 13 16:46:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5789.789257] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=217 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=53787 DPT=6122 LEN=197 
Apr 13 16:46:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5789.793820] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=221 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=47086 DPT=6193 LEN=201 
Apr 13 16:46:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5789.799648] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=194 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=48428 DPT=6157 LEN=174 
Apr 13 16:46:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5789.799752] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=225 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=57981 DPT=6151 LEN=205 
Apr 13 16:47:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5849.760034] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=227 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=54342 DPT=6161 LEN=207 
Apr 13 16:47:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5849.767767] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=211 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=55225 DPT=6131 LEN=191 
Apr 13 16:47:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5849.769004] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=194 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=40362 DPT=6184 LEN=174 
Apr 13 16:47:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5849.769114] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=225 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=52239 DPT=6122 LEN=205 
Apr 13 16:48:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5909.723448] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=227 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=48456 DPT=6179 LEN=207 
Apr 13 16:48:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5909.733470] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=195 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=59141 DPT=6113 LEN=175 
Apr 13 16:48:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5909.739756] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=210 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=40221 DPT=6100 LEN=190 
Apr 13 16:48:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5909.739860] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=225 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=57698 DPT=6197 LEN=205 
Apr 13 16:49:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5969.701304] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=227 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=37077 DPT=6127 LEN=207 
Apr 13 16:49:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5969.709773] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=211 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=45619 DPT=6149 LEN=191 
Apr 13 16:49:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5969.714111] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=194 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=41899 DPT=6106 LEN=174 
Apr 13 16:49:01 ksxxxxxx kernel: [ 5969.714278] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=91.xxx.136.127 DST=91.xxx.136.251 LEN=225 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=56039 DPT=6163 LEN=205
```

Comment: What is the destination IP? Anything you know? Do a tcpdump and look what it says.

Comment: @Sebastian don't know the host, maybe the host provider mirror for apt packages? don't know how to use tcpdump yet, do you have an easy command I could use?

Comment: sudo tcpdump -n -p -i eth0 udp

should give you at least a bit more information.

If you want you can save the packets in a file:

sudo tcpdump -n -p -i eth0 -w trace.pcap udp

You could then upload the trace to http://www.cloudshark.org/ so that we can see it too.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian! Here it is http://www.cloudshark.org/captures/84a949429ebf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at pcap you provided, this traffic comes from a program installed by your hoster OVH called real time monitoring: http://help.ovh.co.uk/RealTimeMonitoring

Never heard of it before. It's sending out information about your server health and configuration. You should ask OVH about it and how to uninstall it.

Seems the install isn't "fresh" but rather a modified install by OVH.